# Check input for telegram login

Tags: php

I have a input:

```
@<input type="text" name="telegram_login" placeholder="Please enter valid login Telegram">
```

I need allow write users only login telegram, not links, not symbols, example : ``@`, ',', '$'` e.t.c, only login. How I can do it?

I tried:

```
$login = str_replace($_POST['telegram_login'], '@', '');
```

But this remove only `@`. But I need and other symbols, I can't know all symbols..

Answer (score 0):

```
$login = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['telegram_login']);
```

Basically it's a regex that will replace anything non alpha numeric.

Comment: But links? Example: telegram.me/@username?

Comment: If you ran this on:  telegram.me/@username you would get:  telegrammeusername

Comment: I need and allow: ` _`

Comment: Then add it to the regex. Remember, white list over blacklist. /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/